# Singularity Grid System showing the grid when using a 'container'

Tags: sass, grid-layout, singularitygs

I have a Singularity layout that puts padding either side of a 'container' like proposed in the Singularity issues here:  https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/issues/91

```
.container {
  // Sets a max width. Site will be fluid until it reaches 960px, then stick there.
  max-width: 960px;
  // Centers the container.
  margin: 0 auto;
  // Sets padding equal to a gutter.
  padding-left: gutter-span();
  padding-right: gutter-span();
  // Might as well clearfix it as well.
  @include clearfix;
}
```

The basic want for this is so there's a gap either side so it looks cushioned on smaller screens.

What I don't understand is on what element I would show the grid using the `@include background-grid` whilst developing.

If I put it on the `.container` then the grid will display under the padding, which is not really part of the grid.  Of course, I could create an element inside that, but that element is purely for visual development purposes and so is redundant once I switch the grid display off.

You can see on the image below how the black line goes out to the edge of it's parent `.container` but the grid is going beyound that.

[image]

Comment: Is this question still actual?

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov yeah, although I think you can use `background-clip: content-box` which is what Susy do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you use padding to add gutters to container. Backgrounds happen to stretch to padding gutters, so your grid is off.

The head-on solution is to use a subcontainer. Apply padding to the outer container. Apply clearfix and grid background to the inner container.

`background-clip: content-box` is indeed a better solution. You don't need debug grid background in IE8 anyway.